# Bash script to parse SNMP output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, snmp

I am working on monitoring a Cisco device where I would need to parse the snmp output and print it in separate more verbose lines.

Through the command line I can do this:

```
snmpwalk -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CISCO-UNIFIED-COMPUTING-STORAGE-MIB.my -v2c -c opennms-Priv X.X.X.X .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.719.1.45.4.1.18 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $4}' | while read -r line ; do echo "Drive $line" ;  done

Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
Drive online(1)
```

However when I use the same in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Output=`snmpwalk -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CISCO-UNIFIED-COMPUTING-STORAGE-MIB.my -v2c -c opennms-Priv 10.201.1.131 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.719.1.45.4.1.18 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $4}'`

while read -r line ; do
        echo "Drive $line";

done << $Output
```

I get this,

```
bash -x CIMC-Monitong.sh
++ snmpwalk -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CISCO-UNIFIED-COMPUTING-STORAGE-MIB.my -v2c -c opennms-Priv X.X.X.X .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.719.1.45.4.1.18
++ awk '{print $4}'
+ Output='online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)
online(1)'
CIMC-Monitong.sh: line 9: warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `$Output')
+ read -r line
+ echo 'Drive '
Drive
+ read -r line
+ echo 'Drive '
Drive
+ read -r line
```

What am I missing?

---

Edit: The reason I didn't pipe it is, right now I am getting output similar to this:

> Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)
>   Drive online(1)

But I expect something like this:

> Drive1 online(1)
>   Drive2 online(1)
>   Drive3 online(1)
>   Drive4 online(1)
>   Drive5 online(1)
>   Drive6 online(1)
>   Drive7 online(1)
>   Drive8 online(1)
>   Drive9 online(1)
>   Drive10 online(1)
>   Drive11 online(1)
>   Drive12 online(1)
>   Drive13 online(1)
>   Drive14 online(1)
>   Drive15 online(1)
>   Drive16 online(1)

Answer (score 1):

The `<<$Output` in the script is interpreted as the start of a here-document.

Usually a here-document is written as, for example,

```
cat <<END_OF_INPUT
.
.
.
.
END_OF_INPUT
```

... but it's totally fine to use `$Output` or any other string as a here-document delimiter.

You probably meant to use `<$Output`, but that would have been wrong too, as that would have been taken as trying to read from the file `$Output`, which is not a filename but the output from your pipeline.

Try piping the output to the while-loop instead, just like you did on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

snmpwalk -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CISCO-UNIFIED-COMPUTING-STORAGE-MIB.my \
  -v2c -c opennms-Priv X.X.X.X .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.719.1.45.4.1.18 2>/dev/null |
awk '{print $4}' |
while read -r line; do 
  echo "Drive $line"
done
```

I tend to use `printf` rather than `echo` when the output needs to contain user-supplied data (any data coming from outside the script, really):

```
printf 'Drive %s\n' "$line"
```

See "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)"

**Updated:**

If your output needs to look like

```
Drive1 online(1)
Drive2 online(1)
... etc.
```

with the number after `Drive` being strictly incrementing by one for each line, then you need a counter in the loop:

```
while read -r line; do 
  printf 'Drive%d %s\n' "$(( ++count ))" "$line"
done
```

Comment: See question edit

Comment: @pradeeps Updated.